# How can I test the functions in this Flask app- write unittests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, redis

````
POOL = redis.ConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/get_cohort_curve/', methods=['GET'])```
def get_cohort_curve():

    curve = str(request.args.get('curve'))
    cohort = str(request.args.get('cohort'))

    key = curve+cohort
    return get_from_redis(key)

def get_from_redis(key):
    try:
        my_server = redis.Redis(connection_pool=POOL)
        return json.dumps(my_server.get(key))
    except Exception, e:
        logging.error(e)

app.run()
````

I need to write unit-tests for this.

How do I test just the route, i.e. a get request goes to the right place?

Do I need to create and destroy instances of the app in the test for each function?

Do I need to create a mock redis connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in running something in Flask, you could create a virtual environment and test the whole shebang, but in my opinion that is THE HARDEST way to do it.

When I built my site installing Redis locally, setting the port and then depositing some data inside it with an appropriate key was essential. I did all of my development in iPython (jupyter) notebooks so that I could test the functions and interactions with Redis before adding the confounding layer of Flask.

Then you set up a flawless template, solid HTML around it and CSS to style the site. If it works without data as an html page, then you move on to the python part of Flask.

Solidify the Flask directories. Make sure that you house them in a virtual environment so that you can call them from your browser and it will treat your virtual environment as a server.

You create your `app.py` application. I created each one of the page functions one at a time. tested to see that it was properly pushing the variables to post on the page and calling the right template. After you get on up and running right, with photos and data, then at the next page's template, using `@app.route`

Take if very slow, one piece at a time with debugging on so that you can see where when and how you are going wrong. You will only get the site to run with redis server on and your virtual environment running.
Then you will have to shut down the VE to edit and reboot to test. At first it is awful, but over time it becomes rote.

**EDIT :**

If you really want to test just the route, then make an app.py with just the @app.route definition and return just the page (the template you are calling). You can break testing into pieces as small as you like, but you have to be sure that the quanta you pick are executable as either a python script in a notebook or commandline execution or as a compact functional self-contained website....unless you use the package I mentioned in the comment: [Flask Unit Testing Applications](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/testing/)

And you need to create REAL Redis connections or you will error out.

Comment: It needs to have unit-tests for this code to go into production.

I see what you are saying- I tested the code on a Jupyter notebook using a redis server running locally.

Comment: There is built in funtionality for unit testing. Here is the link to it: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/testing/  . But unit testing can be done manually as well. My process above includes unit testing at each step.